# How to not restart my app when the Home button is pressed?

Tags: android, android-homebutton

I have an app that uses `intent-filters` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file to start an `Activity` when the Home button is pressed. Thing is, if my app is on that time in a different activity, the `LoginActivity` is started again and the user has to log in again. I want the Home button to do nothing if my app is on top.

How could I do that?

```
    <activity 
        android:name="com.example.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

Comment: maybe you could set a variable and check if it contains a number for example and if so skip over login?

Comment: May be you will tell more about your project, are you creating a launcher app?

Comment: @KirillShalnov no, I am building a single-function device. The users should not be able to start other apps easily, so I made my app a startup app.

Answer (score 0):

Is not advisable to change the Home button functionality, because doing so it would be a negative user experience. Instead, you could store into a variable a boolean if the user is logged in, and if true, jump directly on to the main activity.

I don't know what is your launch activity, but if it is the login activity, you could check on the onStart method what I said, and then start the other activity.

Comment: I change Home button functionality, because these phones are used as a single-function device in an industrial environment.

Answer (score 0):

You shoud to check by your own trigger (static variable?) that your app is working and user logged in early, then start another activity and finish current

**OR**

try this
`android:launchMode="singleTop"`
in your manifest to the activities.

Comment: Thanks, but in fact, I dont' want to start anything at all. Just "don't touch the running app".

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to do this:

1. Works between 2.3 and 4.0:

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
       if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)) {
           // do nothing                     
           return true;
       }
       return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
   }
   ```
2. Also works between 2.3 and 4.0:

   ```
   @Override public void onAttachedToWindow() { 
       this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);
       super.onAttachedToWindow(); 
   }
   ```
3. This involves overriding the method [`onUserLeaveHint()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserLeaveHint%28%29):

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onUserLeaveHint() {
       Intent intent = getIntent();
       intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
       ((AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(ALARM)).set(1,
               System.currentTimeMillis(),
               PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0));
       }
       super.onUserLeaveHint();
   }
   ```

Comment: my device is 4.3. Haven't tried number 3 though. Currently I am going towards giving the instruction "don't touch the home button" :)

Comment: I believe option 3 is what you want :)